# Add Fields to the Link Module

Tags: 7, entities, navigation

Image here: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiPgw.png]

I made this with Photoshop. The "URL" field is supposed to be a Link field (the [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) module). But it seems that it only provides an optional title field but no way to add fields like this. Or should I create a new node type and add "Quality" and "Provider" fields then reference (the Entity Reference module) that node with this? Seems that adding those two fields are more ideal. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but apart from looking Field Collection, check Field Group module

Answer (score 3):

There is a module just for this, where you can add and group fields together, as well as add multiple field groups: [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)